# closing Azure Servicebus subscription after expiring SAS token

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have created a servicebus topic subscription using SAS token. The SAS token expires after 5mins.

I have registered a function to be called on message and another one on exception.

```
var messageOptions = new OnMessageOptions();   
messageOptions.ExceptionReceived += onMessageException;   
mySubscriptionClient.OnMessage(studyBolusMessageCallBack, messageOptions);
```

After SAS expiry the exception function is calling repeatedly. I want this to be called only once for recreating the subscription using new SAS token. Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please a try to set `MaxDeliveryCount = 1` on subcription

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tom. I'm getting this exception on expiry of SAS token not for a message.